# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:1'

Tags: php

I'm having this problem with my website site is built on prestashop and everything is working perfectly only at times I get alerts that site urls are having 500 error, but when I click on same url I see it active. Contacted host and they confirmed all configurations are properly set.

Going through my error logs, I saw this error but don't know how to fix it.

> Error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: Unable to load template
>   'file:1' <--   thrown in
>   /home/lords/public_html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php
>   on line 195

Can you please help?

Regards.

```
<?php

class Smarty_Internal_Template extends Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase
{
    /**
     * Template object cache
     *
     * @var Smarty_Internal_Template[]
     */
    public static $tplObjCache = array();

    /**
     * Template object cache for Smarty::isCached() === true
     *
     * @var Smarty_Internal_Template[]
     */
    public static $isCacheTplObj = array();

    /**
     * Sub template Info Cache
     * - index name
     * - value use count
     *
     * @var int[]
     */
    public static $subTplInfo = array();

    /**
     * This object type (Smarty = 1, template = 2, data = 4)
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $_objType = 2;

    /**
     * Global smarty instance
     *
     * @var Smarty
     */
    public $smarty = null;

    /**
     * Source instance
     *
     * @var Smarty_Template_Source|Smarty_Template_Config
     */
    public $source = null;

    /**
     * Inheritance runtime extension
     *
     * @var Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance
     */
    public $inheritance = null;

    /**
     * Template resource
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $template_resource = null;

    /**
     * flag if compiled template is invalid and must be (re)compiled
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $mustCompile = null;

    /**
     * Template Id
     *
     * @var null|string
     */
    public $templateId = null;

    /**
     * Scope in which variables shall be assigned
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $scope = 0;

    /**
     * Flag which is set while rending a cache file
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $isRenderingCache = false;

    /**
     * Callbacks called before rendering template
     *
     * @var callback[]
     */
    public $startRenderCallbacks = array();

    /**
     * Callbacks called after rendering template
     *
     * @var callback[]
     */
    public $endRenderCallbacks = array();

    /**
     * Create template data object
     * Some of the global Smarty settings copied to template scope
     * It load the required template resources and caching plugins
     *
     * @param string                                                       $template_resource template resource string
     * @param Smarty                                                       $smarty            Smarty instance
     * @param null|\Smarty_Internal_Template|\Smarty|\Smarty_Internal_Data $_parent           back pointer to parent
     *                                                                                        object with variables or
     *                                                                                        null
     * @param mixed                                                        $_cache_id         cache   id or null
     * @param mixed                                                        $_compile_id       compile id or null
     * @param bool|int|null                                                $_caching          use caching?
     * @param int|null                                                     $_cache_lifetime   cache life-time in
     *                                                                                        seconds
     * @param bool                                                         $_isConfig
     *
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function __construct(
        $template_resource,
        Smarty $smarty,
        Smarty_Internal_Data $_parent = null,
        $_cache_id = null,
        $_compile_id = null,
        $_caching = null,
        $_cache_lifetime = null,
        $_isConfig = false
    ) {
        $this->smarty = $smarty;
        // Smarty parameter
        $this->cache_id = $_cache_id === null ? $this->smarty->cache_id : $_cache_id;
        $this->compile_id = $_compile_id === null ? $this->smarty->compile_id : $_compile_id;
        $this->caching = (int)($_caching === null ? $this->smarty->caching : $_caching);
        $this->cache_lifetime = $_cache_lifetime === null ? $this->smarty->cache_lifetime : $_cache_lifetime;
        $this->compile_check = (int)$smarty->compile_check;
        $this->parent = $_parent;
        // Template resource
        $this->template_resource = $template_resource;
        $this->source = $_isConfig ? Smarty_Template_Config::load($this) : Smarty_Template_Source::load($this);
        parent::__construct();
        if ($smarty->security_policy && method_exists($smarty->security_policy, 'registerCallBacks')) {
            $smarty->security_policy->registerCallBacks($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * render template
     *
     * @param bool      $no_output_filter if true do not run output filter
     * @param null|bool $display          true: display, false: fetch null: sub-template
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function render($no_output_filter = true, $display = null)
    {
        if ($this->smarty->debugging) {
            if (!isset($this->smarty->_debug)) {
                $this->smarty->_debug = new Smarty_Internal_Debug();
            }
            $this->smarty->_debug->start_template($this, $display);
        }
        // checks if template exists
        if (!$this->source->exists) {
            throw new SmartyException(
                "Unable to load template '{$this->source->type}:{$this->source->name}'" .
                ($this->_isSubTpl() ? " in '{$this->parent->template_resource}'" : '')
            );
        }
        // disable caching for evaluated code
        if ($this->source->handler->recompiled) {
            $this->caching = Smarty::CACHING_OFF;
        }
        // read from cache or render
        if ($this->caching === Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_CURRENT || $this->caching === Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_SAVED) {
            if (!isset($this->cached) || $this->cached->cache_id !== $this->cache_id
                || $this->cached->compile_id !== $this->compile_id
            ) {
                $this->loadCached(true);
            }
            $this->cached->render($this, $no_output_filter);
        } else {
            if (!isset($this->compiled) || $this->compiled->compile_id !== $this->compile_id) {
                $this->loadCompiled(true);
            }
            $this->compiled->render($this);
        }
        // display or fetch
        if ($display) {
            if ($this->caching && $this->smarty->cache_modified_check) {
                $this->smarty->ext->_cacheModify->cacheModifiedCheck(
                    $this->cached,
                    $this,
                    isset($content) ? $content : ob_get_clean()
                );
            } else {
                if ((!$this->caching || $this->cached->has_nocache_code || $this->source->handler->recompiled)
                    && !$no_output_filter && (isset($this->smarty->autoload_filters[ 'output' ])
                                              || isset($this->smarty->registered_filters[ 'output' ]))
                ) {
                    echo $this->smarty->ext->_filterHandler->runFilter('output', ob_get_clean(), $this);
                } else {
                    echo ob_get_clean();
                }
            }
            if ($this->smarty->debugging) {
                $this->smarty->_debug->end_template($this);
                // debug output
                $this->smarty->_debug->display_debug($this, true);
            }
            return '';
        } else {
            if ($this->smarty->debugging) {
                $this->smarty->_debug->end_template($this);
                if ($this->smarty->debugging === 2 && $display === false) {
                    $this->smarty->_debug->display_debug($this, true);
                }
            }
            if (!$no_output_filter
                && (!$this->caching || $this->cached->has_nocache_code || $this->source->handler->recompiled)
                && (isset($this->smarty->autoload_filters[ 'output' ])
                    || isset($this->smarty->registered_filters[ 'output' ]))
            ) {
                return $this->smarty->ext->_filterHandler->runFilter('output', ob_get_clean(), $this);
            }
            // return cache content
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runtime function to render sub-template
     *
     * @param string  $template       template name
     * @param mixed   $cache_id       cache id
     * @param mixed   $compile_id     compile id
     * @param integer $caching        cache mode
     * @param integer $cache_lifetime life time of cache data
     * @param array   $data           passed parameter template variables
     * @param int     $scope          scope in which {include} should execute
     * @param bool    $forceTplCache  cache template object
     * @param string  $uid            file dependency uid
     * @param string  $content_func   function name
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function _subTemplateRender(
        $template,
        $cache_id,
        $compile_id,
        $caching,
        $cache_lifetime,
        $data,
        $scope,
        $forceTplCache,
        $uid = null,
        $content_func = null
    ) {
        $tpl = clone $this;
        $tpl->parent = $this;
        $smarty = &$this->smarty;
        $_templateId = $smarty->_getTemplateId($template, $cache_id, $compile_id, $caching, $tpl);
        // recursive call ?
        if (isset($tpl->templateId) ? $tpl->templateId : $tpl->_getTemplateId() !== $_templateId) {
            // already in template cache?
            if (isset(self::$tplObjCache[ $_templateId ])) {
                // copy data from cached object
                $cachedTpl = &self::$tplObjCache[ $_templateId ];
                $tpl->templateId = $cachedTpl->templateId;
                $tpl->template_resource = $cachedTpl->template_resource;
                $tpl->cache_id = $cachedTpl->cache_id;
                $tpl->compile_id = $cachedTpl->compile_id;
                $tpl->source = $cachedTpl->source;
                if (isset($cachedTpl->compiled)) {
                    $tpl->compiled = $cachedTpl->compiled;
                } else {
                    unset($tpl->compiled);
                }
                if ($caching !== 9999 && isset($cachedTpl->cached)) {
                    $tpl->cached = $cachedTpl->cached;
                } else {
                    unset($tpl->cached);
                }
            } else {
                $tpl->templateId = $_templateId;
                $tpl->template_resource = $template;
                $tpl->cache_id = $cache_id;
                $tpl->compile_id = $compile_id;
                if (isset($uid)) {
                    // for inline templates we can get all resource information from file dependency
                    list($filepath, $timestamp, $type) = $tpl->compiled->file_dependency[ $uid ];
                    $tpl->source = new Smarty_Template_Source($smarty, $filepath, $type, $filepath);
                    $tpl->source->filepath = $filepath;
                    $tpl->source->timestamp = $timestamp;
                    $tpl->source->exists = true;
                    $tpl->source->uid = $uid;
                } else {
                    $tpl->source = Smarty_Template_Source::load($tpl);
                    unset($tpl->compiled);
                }
                if ($caching !== 9999) {
                    unset($tpl->cached);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // on recursive calls force caching
            $forceTplCache = true;
        }
        $tpl->caching = $caching;
        $tpl->cache_lifetime = $cache_lifetime;
        // set template scope
        $tpl->scope = $scope;
        if (!isset(self::$tplObjCache[ $tpl->templateId ]) && !$tpl->source->handler->recompiled) {
            // check if template object should be cached
            if ($forceTplCache || (isset(self::$subTplInfo[ $tpl->template_resource ])
                                   && self::$subTplInfo[ $tpl->template_resource ] > 1)
                || ($tpl->_isSubTpl() && isset(self::$tplObjCache[ $tpl->parent->templateId ]))
            ) {
                self::$tplObjCache[ $tpl->templateId ] = $tpl;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($data)) {
            // set up variable values
            foreach ($data as $_key => $_val) {
                $tpl->tpl_vars[ $_key ] = new Smarty_Variable($_val, $this->isRenderingCache);
            }
        }
        if ($tpl->caching === 9999) {
            if (!isset($tpl->compiled)) {
                $this->loadCompiled(true);
            }
            if ($tpl->compiled->has_nocache_code) {
                $this->cached->hashes[ $tpl->compiled->nocache_hash ] = true;
            }
        }
        $tpl->_cache = array();
        if (isset($uid)) {
            if ($smarty->debugging) {
                if (!isset($smarty->_debug)) {
                    $smarty->_debug = new Smarty_Internal_Debug();
                }
                $smarty->_debug->start_template($tpl);
                $smarty->_debug->start_render($tpl);
            }
            $tpl->compiled->getRenderedTemplateCode($tpl, $content_func);
            if ($smarty->debugging) {
                $smarty->_debug->end_template($tpl);
                $smarty->_debug->end_render($tpl);
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($tpl->compiled)) {
                $tpl->compiled->render($tpl);
            } else {
                $tpl->render();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get called sub-templates and save call count
     */
    public function _subTemplateRegister()
    {
        foreach ($this->compiled->includes as $name => $count) {
            if (isset(self::$subTplInfo[ $name ])) {
                self::$subTplInfo[ $name ] += $count;
            } else {
                self::$subTplInfo[ $name ] = $count;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if this is a sub template
     *
     * @return bool true is sub template
     */
    public function _isSubTpl()
    {
        return isset($this->parent) && $this->parent->_isTplObj();
    }

    /**
     * Assign variable in scope
     *
     * @param string $varName variable name
     * @param mixed  $value   value
     * @param bool   $nocache nocache flag
     * @param int    $scope   scope into which variable shall be assigned
     */
    public function _assignInScope($varName, $value, $nocache = false, $scope = 0)
    {
        if (isset($this->tpl_vars[ $varName ])) {
            $this->tpl_vars[ $varName ] = clone $this->tpl_vars[ $varName ];
            $this->tpl_vars[ $varName ]->value = $value;
            if ($nocache || $this->isRenderingCache) {
                $this->tpl_vars[ $varName ]->nocache = true;
            }
        } else {
            $this->tpl_vars[ $varName ] = new Smarty_Variable($value, $nocache || $this->isRenderingCache);
        }
        if ($scope >= 0) {
            if ($scope > 0 || $this->scope > 0) {
                $this->smarty->ext->_updateScope->_updateScope($this, $varName, $scope);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if plugins are callable require file otherwise
     *
     * @param array $plugins required plugins
     *
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function _checkPlugins($plugins)
    {
        static $checked = array();
        foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
            $name = join('::', (array)$plugin[ 'function' ]);
            if (!isset($checked[ $name ])) {
                if (!is_callable($plugin[ 'function' ])) {
                    if (is_file($plugin[ 'file' ])) {
                        include_once $plugin[ 'file' ];
                        if (is_callable($plugin[ 'function' ])) {
                            $checked[ $name ] = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $checked[ $name ] = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isset($checked[ $name ])) {
                if (false !== $this->smarty->loadPlugin($name)) {
                    $checked[ $name ] = true;
                } else {
                    throw new SmartyException("Plugin '{$name}' not callable");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function is executed automatically when a compiled or cached template file is included
     * - Decode saved properties from compiled template and cache files
     * - Check if compiled or cache file is valid
     *
     * @param \Smarty_Internal_Template $tpl
     * @param array                     $properties special template properties
     * @param bool                      $cache      flag if called from cache file
     *
     * @return bool flag if compiled or cache file is valid
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function _decodeProperties(Smarty_Internal_Template $tpl, $properties, $cache = false)
    {
        // on cache resources other than file check version stored in cache code
        if (!isset($properties[ 'version' ]) || Smarty::SMARTY_VERSION !== $properties[ 'version' ]) {
            if ($cache) {
                $tpl->smarty->clearAllCache();
            } else {
                $tpl->smarty->clearCompiledTemplate();
            }
            return false;
        }
        $is_valid = true;
        if (!empty($properties[ 'file_dependency' ])
            && ((!$cache && $tpl->compile_check) || $tpl->compile_check === Smarty::COMPILECHECK_ON)
        ) {
            // check file dependencies at compiled code
            foreach ($properties[ 'file_dependency' ] as $_file_to_check) {
                if ($_file_to_check[ 2 ] === 'file' || $_file_to_check[ 2 ] === 'php') {
                    if ($tpl->source->filepath === $_file_to_check[ 0 ]) {
                        // do not recheck current template
                        continue;
                        //$mtime = $tpl->source->getTimeStamp();
                    } else {
                        // file and php types can be checked without loading the respective resource handlers
                        $mtime = is_file($_file_to_check[ 0 ]) ? filemtime($_file_to_check[ 0 ]) : false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $handler = Smarty_Resource::load($tpl->smarty, $_file_to_check[ 2 ]);
                    if ($handler->checkTimestamps()) {
                        $source = Smarty_Template_Source::load($tpl, $tpl->smarty, $_file_to_check[ 0 ]);
                        $mtime = $source->getTimeStamp();
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if ($mtime === false || $mtime > $_file_to_check[ 1 ]) {
                    $is_valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($cache) {
            // CACHING_LIFETIME_SAVED cache expiry has to be validated here since otherwise we'd define the unifunc
            if ($tpl->caching === Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_SAVED && $properties[ 'cache_lifetime' ] >= 0
                && (time() > ($tpl->cached->timestamp + $properties[ 'cache_lifetime' ]))
            ) {
                $is_valid = false;
            }
            $tpl->cached->cache_lifetime = $properties[ 'cache_lifetime' ];
            $tpl->cached->valid = $is_valid;
            $resource = $tpl->cached;
        } else {
            $tpl->mustCompile = !$is_valid;
            $resource = $tpl->compiled;
            $resource->includes = isset($properties[ 'includes' ]) ? $properties[ 'includes' ] : array();
        }
        if ($is_valid) {
            $resource->unifunc = $properties[ 'unifunc' ];
            $resource->has_nocache_code = $properties[ 'has_nocache_code' ];
            //            $tpl->compiled->nocache_hash = $properties['nocache_hash'];
            $resource->file_dependency = $properties[ 'file_dependency' ];
        }
        return $is_valid && !function_exists($properties[ 'unifunc' ]);
    }

    /**
     * Compiles the template
     * If the template is not evaluated the compiled template is saved on disk
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function compileTemplateSource()
    {
        return $this->compiled->compileTemplateSource($this);
    }

    /**
     * Writes the content to cache resource
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function writeCachedContent($content)
    {
        return $this->smarty->ext->_updateCache->writeCachedContent($this, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Get unique template id
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function _getTemplateId()
    {
        return isset($this->templateId) ? $this->templateId : $this->templateId =
            $this->smarty->_getTemplateId($this->template_resource, $this->cache_id, $this->compile_id);
    }

    /**
     * runtime error not matching capture tags
     *
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function capture_error()
    {
        throw new SmartyException("Not matching {capture} open/close in '{$this->template_resource}'");
    }

    /**
     * Load compiled object
     *
     * @param bool $force force new compiled object
     */
    public function loadCompiled($force = false)
    {
        if ($force || !isset($this->compiled)) {
            $this->compiled = Smarty_Template_Compiled::load($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load cached object
     *
     * @param bool $force force new cached object
     */
    public function loadCached($force = false)
    {
        if ($force || !isset($this->cached)) {
            $this->cached = Smarty_Template_Cached::load($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load inheritance object
     */
    public function _loadInheritance()
    {
        if (!isset($this->inheritance)) {
            $this->inheritance = new Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unload inheritance object
     */
    public function _cleanUp()
    {
        $this->startRenderCallbacks = array();
        $this->endRenderCallbacks = array();
        $this->inheritance = null;
    }

    /**
     * Load compiler object
     *
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function loadCompiler()
    {
        if (!class_exists($this->source->compiler_class)) {
            $this->smarty->loadPlugin($this->source->compiler_class);
        }
        $this->compiler =
            new $this->source->compiler_class(
                $this->source->template_lexer_class,
                $this->source->template_parser_class,
                $this->smarty
            );
    }

    /**
     * Handle unknown class methods
     *
     * @param string $name unknown method-name
     * @param array  $args argument array
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        // method of Smarty object?
        if (method_exists($this->smarty, $name)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->smarty, $name), $args);
        }
        // parent
        return parent::__call($name, $args);
    }

    /**
     * get Smarty property in template context
     *
     * @param string $property_name property name
     *
     * @return mixed|Smarty_Template_Cached
     * @throws SmartyException
     */
    public function __get($property_name)
    {
        switch ($property_name) {
            case 'compiled':
                $this->loadCompiled();
                return $this->compiled;
            case 'cached':
                $this->loadCached();
                return $this->cached;
            case 'compiler':
                $this->loadCompiler();
                return $this->compiler;
            default:
                // Smarty property ?
                if (property_exists($this->smarty, $property_name)) {
                    return $this->smarty->$property_name;
                }
        }
        throw new SmartyException("template property '$property_name' does not exist.");
    }

    /**
     * set Smarty property in template context
     *
     * @param string $property_name property name
     * @param mixed  $value         value
     *
     * @throws SmartyException
     */
    public function __set($property_name, $value)
    {
        switch ($property_name) {
            case 'compiled':
            case 'cached':
            case 'compiler':
                $this->$property_name = $value;
                return;
            default:
                // Smarty property ?
                if (property_exists($this->smarty, $property_name)) {
                    $this->smarty->$property_name = $value;
                    return;
                }
        }
        throw new SmartyException("invalid template property '$property_name'.");
    }

    /**
     * Template data object destructor
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        if ($this->smarty->cache_locking && isset($this->cached) && $this->cached->is_locked) {
            $this->cached->handler->releaseLock($this->smarty, $this->cached);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let post code in file .tpl what you call display.

Comment: Which line is line 195 in file `smarty_internal_template.php` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks guys for your response and my apologies for getting back late.

The error was caused by a module, and I've resolved it by reseting the module.

Best regards.